# PHP Contact Form - Single field not populating

Tags: php

HTML for my fields and contact block, my fields are Name, Number. Email, Subject, Message. All of my fields work properly and when submitted I receive the email perfectly, apart from the Number field which for some reason does not populate with the amount or any value at all

---

```
<!-- contact section -->
```

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="section-header">
                <h2 class="wow fadeInDown animated">Contact Us</h2>
                <p class="wow fadeInDown animated">Please fill in your contact details below and we will get back to you.<br>Alternatively contact us on: 031 464 4801 | 083 555 1202</p>
            </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 conForm">       

        <form method="post" action="php/email.php" name="cform" id="cform" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
          <div id="message"></div>
          <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" placeholder="Your name..." >
          <input name="cell" id="cell" type="number" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" placeholder="Your Number..." >
          <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 noMarr" placeholder="Email Address..." >
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="" rows="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          <!-- START CAPTCHA -->



<br>
<div class="capbox">

<div id="CaptchaDiv"></div>

<div class="capbox-inner">
Type the above number:<br>

<input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha">
<input type="text" name="CaptchaInput" id="CaptchaInput" size="15"><br>

</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<!-- END CAPTCHA -->
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="submitBnt" value="Send">
          <div id="simple-msg"></div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">

// Captcha Script

function checkform(theform){
var why = "";

if(theform.CaptchaInput.value == ""){
why += "- Please Enter CAPTCHA Code.\n";
}
if(theform.CaptchaInput.value != ""){
if(ValidCaptcha(theform.CaptchaInput.value) == false){
why += "- The CAPTCHA Code Does Not Match.\n";
}
}
if(why != ""){
alert(why);
return false;
}
}

var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';

var code = a + b + c + d + e;
document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
document.getElementById("CaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;

// Validate input against the generated number
function ValidCaptcha(){
var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('CaptchaInput').value);
if (str1 == str2){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}

// Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
function removeSpaces(string){
return string.split(' ').join('');
}
</script>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

This is the PHP which pushes the mail, values and email format through to my address, again, everything seems to be in order and works fine, apart from the number (cell) field, which does not populate with any information, no matter what you put into it.

---

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter( 'nocache' );

$to = "bjorn@tech5.co.za";  //Recipient's E-mail

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message  = 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Number: ' . $_REQUEST['cell'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "<br>";
$message .= $_REQUEST['comments'];


if (@mail($to, 'New Inquiry from Executive Plant Hire', $message, $headers))
{

    mail('bjorn@tech5.co.za', 'New Inquiry from Executive Plant Hire', $message, $headers);
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
    echo '<label class="lbl lbl-success">Your email has been sent successfully, we will be in touch</label>';
    // header('Location: ../index.html');
}
else
{
    // Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
    echo '<label class="lbl lbl-warning">There was a problem sending you request, please contact us directly</label>';
}
```

### ?>

Can anyone provide some assistance or advise what I might be doing wrong? I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to work... any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors. Can you post the code for `checkform()`?

Comment: _“I've tried everything I can think of”_ - and how much - or little - was that actually …? Maybe you should start by checking what gets actually send from the client (browser dev tools, network panel.)

Comment: Number field? Do you mean the field named `cell` or something else?

Comment: @GetSet Thanks for the reply, I've included all the code for my <!--contact section--> Let me know what your thoughts are, as mentioned, everything works, apart from the stuid cell/number field...

Comment: @Dave Hey Dave, front end the field with placeholder is called "Your Number" 
back-end name & id = cell and type = number

Comment: The input type number is supposed to fallback to a text field if not supported. But what happens if you change the type to text?

Comment: Could the baked-in validation of `number` be invalidating the entry? Have you considered using `<input type="tel">` since your intent here is to capture a telephone number?

Comment: Good catch @Robert. Upvote. Thats what's going on likely for OP. I just tested it. Any symbol will return nil for that value.

Comment: I've tested with both type="text" and type="tel" - both result in the same error. I've attached a screenshot of what i'm receiving upon submission, here: http://www.lundbergs.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/blankfield.png

Comment: @GetSet thanks for picking up on that! Saves me the headache of going through that error once this one is resolved :p

I've updated so that type="tel" and have tested - type="text" as well, both of which lead me to the same error as seen here: lundbergs.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/blankfield.png

For whatever reason, that field isn't being populated or pulling information?

Comment: Are your sure you saved all your files? I just tested your exact code (without sending the mail out of course!) and got these results on a `print_r()` of `$_REQUEST`. .... Array ( [name] => Me [cell] => 123456 [email] => 23@e.com [comments] => Something here [CaptchaInput] => 62591 [send] => Send )

Comment: This is why I'm so confused! xD

I can't for the life of me understand where the issue is? Your test looks perfect, yet I can't shake this error, I am 100% certain all changes have been saved.

The website i'm working on is planthireservices.co.za
I can CC you in the mail once form has been submitted if you'd like to view the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

@Bjorn,

You can see here that entering any non-digit char (like a symbol that might go in a telephone number), will invalidate the number field.

```html
<input type="number" id="check">
<button type="button" onclick="console.log(document.getElementById('check').value)">Check</button>
```